# What is wrong with the value of an object in union declaration?

Tags: c, embedded

When running the following code i expect the value of Z to equal 3 too like x and y because it is the dominating variable but i get this results :

```
3
3
4194307
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.015 s
Press any key to continue.
```

the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// unions //
union u1 {
    char x;
    short int y;
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    union u1 A;
    A.x=3;
    //A.y=258;
    printf("%d\n",A.x);
    printf("%d\n",A.y);
    printf("%d\n",A.z);
   /* A.y=258;
    printf("%d\n",A.x);
    printf("%d\n",A.y);
    printf("%d\n",A.z); */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behavior is undefined if you try to read a union member other than the one that was last assigned.

Comment: You're only assigning 1 byte of the union. So the other 3 bytes of `z` continue to hold whatever garbage they originally contained.

Comment: your value in hex is `0x400003`

Comment: @Barmar: Re “The behavior is undefined if you try to read a union member other than the one that was last assigned”: No, it is not. The behavior is defined to interpret the bytes of the union in the new type. (In C++ the behavior is not defined.)

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not define any “dominating variable” for a union. A union consists of members with equal status except that, when initializing a union with no member designator, the first named member is used.

The members of a union share the bytes of a union. When a value is stored in a union member, the bytes that do not correspond to that member take unspecified values, per C 2018 6.2.6.1 6 and 7. (This means they get definite values but those values are not specified by the C standard and may be different in each store operation.)

So `A.x=3;` sets the byte for member `x` to 3 and may set the other bytes to any values.

In C, when you read a union member other than the last one stored, the bytes of the union are reinterpreted as the type of the new member, per C 2018 6.5.2.3 3 and note 99. (In C++, the behavior is not defined by the C++ standard.) Getting the value 3 for `A.y` shows the byte for `A.y` that is not shared with `A.x` was set to 0.

For `A.z`, you got 4,194,307. In hexadecimal, that is 00400003<sub>16</sub>. This shows that the remaining two bytes were set to 00<sub>16</sub> and 40<sub>16</sub>. It also reveals your C implementation stores the bytes of a `short` and an `int` in little-endian order (the byte with the least position value is stored first).

Comment: _A.x=3; sets the byte for member x to 3 and may set the other bytes to any values_: probably not. It justs sets x to 3.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: There is no probably or probably not about it; the statement says it “may” set the other bytes, and that is true 100% of the time. As I wrote, the C standard specifies this in C 2018 6.2.6.1 6 and 7. Whether or not the other bytes are set to new values is a different question. It also is typically not a matter of probability but of the compiler design, the target platform, and circumstances around the assignment…

Comment: … C 2018 6.2.6.1 6 and 7 specify that the other bytes take unspecified values. Those values may be whatever was already in them, they may be zero bytes if the compiler chooses to store 3 as an entire four-byte `int`, or they may be other values. Of note is they take *unspecified* values and not *indeterminate* values. Once a byte takes an unspecified value, it does not change absent modification by the program. A byte said to have an *indeterminate* value need not have a fixed value; it may appear to change each time it is nominally accessed.

Comment: I think you mean "remaining three bytes".

Comment: @Barmar: Byte 0 was set by `A.x=3;`. Byte 1 was discussed in discussing the `short`. The remaining 2 bytes are bytes 2 and 3, discussed with the `int`.